# Apache ODE & Oracle 11

Tags: java, oracle11g, bpel, apache-ode

I'm trying to make my apache ode 1.3.5 on tomcat 7 using Oracle 11.
I'm facing plenty of errors when trying to access data.

Does anyone succeed to make this kind of configuration works ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Currently this one :
Caused by: javax.transaction.NotSupportedException: nested transactions not supported
 at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager.begin(BitronixTransactionManager.java:97)
 at org.apache.ode.axis2.ODEService.onAxisMessageExchange(ODEService.java:117)

But I corrected several others before, which seems to me that ODE is not stable on Oracle

Comment: ODE use OpenJPA [for connecting to its database](http://ode.apache.org/databases.html). So maybe this is rather a OpenJPA / Oracle 11 g compatibility problem?

Comment: Ok. I'll have a look. I've move forward and now it seems that it's geronimo problem : 14:28:37,375 | ERROR | ODEService |  -  | Commit failed
javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
 at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:271)
 at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:238)

Comment: I have seen flawlessly working deployments of ODE with its Hibernate DAOs on JBoss with Oracle. So I assume its a configuration issue in your case.

Comment: Probably, maybe you can post a sample of a working one so I can check some differences with mine ?